¿Cómo puedo cambiar el color de un archivo SVG con filter para que sea un color en especifico?
Buen día a todos, tengo un problema y es que me gustaría cambiar el color de un archivo SVG, pero como no encuentro el valor del color directamente en el SVG, y se me ocurrió cambiarlo con los estilos del HTML invirtiendo el color original, que es negro, con un filtro de CSS, ya que el fill no me funciona no se porque, así:
filter: invert(47%) sepia(77%) saturate(497%) hue-rotate(31deg) brightness(91%) contrast(98%);

Pero no logro que tenga el color que yo quiero, es parecido pero me gustaría que sea igual para que no se vea la frontera entre un elemento y otro, el color es: #a9e159
Así es como se ve con los valores que les estoy comentando:

el pasto es el archivo SVG y el cuadro verde de abajo es el color que necesito, bueno son varios archivos SVG pero le estoy aplicando los estilos a todos, los saque de esta página: https://www.svgrepo.com/vectors/grass/monocolor/
Así se ve en el HTML (sin el cuadro de abajo)
<div class="pasto" id="pasto">
    <div class="repetir" id="repetir">
        <img src="img/pasto/grass-leaf-plant-11-svgrepo-com.svg" alt="">
        <img src="img/pasto/grass-leaf-plant-12-svgrepo-com.svg" alt="">
        <img src="img/pasto/grass-leaf-plant-20-svgrepo-com.svg" alt="">
        <img src="img/pasto/grass-leaf-plant-4-svgrepo-com.svg" alt="">
        <img src="img/pasto/grass-leaf-plant-7-svgrepo-com.svg" alt="">
        <img src="img/pasto/grass-leaf-plant-8-svgrepo-com.svg" alt="">
    </div>
</div>

y así tengo los estilos:
.pasto {
background-color: #ffffff;
width: 100%;
display: flex;
overflow: hidden;
color: #a9e159;
}

.repetir {
    display: flex;
    translate: -15%;
}

.pasto img {
    width: 150px;
    line-height: 150px;
    margin-right: -100px;
    margin-bottom: -5px;
    filter: invert(47%) sepia(77%) saturate(497%) hue-rotate(31deg) brightness(91%) contrast(98%);
}

No se si tenga que agregar el código del SVG para ayudar a resolver mi duda.
Muchas gracias de antemano.

Ya revise ese, pero lo que quiero es que el color verde sea igual que el cuadro de abajo, ya le movi mucho pero solo logro otros tonos de verde, creo que si aclare eso en la pregunta @Marcos

oh, ya, me sirve, no encontraba una herramienta que generara un color tan parecido ahora se ve como quería, muchas gracias.
PD: soy nuevo aquí como le pongo para que sepan que ya respondieron a mi pregunta? @Marcos

Damián, no hay problema. Esto son solo comentarios. Tenes 2 opciones, aceptar que la pregunta es duplicada o crear vos una respuesta a tu propia pregunta detallando cómo llegaste a la solución.

Me recomendaron una Herramienta en los comentarios para mi pregunta, estoy seguro de que me servirá más de lo que piensan y dejare la pregunta con esta respuesta para que puedan encontrar una respuesta a quienes tienen una pregunta especifica como esta, a veces es de mucha ayuda preguntas así.
Esta herramienta sirve para convertir un color a sus valores dentro de un filtro
El color que buscaba es: #a9e159, y al convertirlo en los valores de un filtro es:
filter: invert(82%) sepia(29%) saturate(788%) hue-rotate(34deg) brightness(97%) contrast(92%);

y es el color que buscaba:

y es como quería que se viera, muchas gracias de verdad.

Si, muchas gracias

La propiedad fillno te funciona porque solo sirve si estás usando la etiqueta html <svg>, si éste lo añades a través de la etiqueta <img>o través del código css no funcionará.
Lo único que puedes hacer es lo que comentas de usar la propiedad filter.

Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas en el centro de ayuda.
